# Why did my items Dissapear

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Yesterday When I logged on to my world. I wanted to make a supermarket, which I made yesterday and then I filled up items on the slabs and then sometime afterward. It disappears on its own. This was In the version of minecraft 1.20. Please fix this issue Mojang

Comment: It seems you are talking to Mojang, but we are not Mojang.

Comment: You never know, maybe we are Mojang...

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you dont just drop the items on top of the slab, this will cause them to despawn after 5 minutes.